# Log In example with xQuery

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, xquery

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to evaluate the login credentials for a restricted area of a database.

this is my code:

```
declare function local:check() as xs:string {

let $login :=  request:get-parameter("username",'')
let $password :=  request:get-parameter("password",'')

let $user := doc('credentials.xml')/credenziali/utente[./user = $login]

return (
    if (not(empty($user))) then concat('staff.xq',$login,' ',$password)
    else concat('login_error.xq',$login,' ',$password)
)    
};
```

This function is called in:

```
form name="login" method="post" action="{local:check()}"
```

but I can not understand why I am always redirected to the page ''login_error'' (ie the user object always empty) despite i enter correct credentials (available in the file credentials.xml).

Credentials.xml contain:

`<credenziali> 
   <utente id="1"> 
     <user>admin</user> 
     <password>admin</password> 
   </utente> 
 </credenziali>`

and i set, in the respective input text box of screen, username=admin and password=admin

Comment: the only control is on user = login (and not on password) just for simplicity;)

Answer (score 2):

Without more information it's hard to see exactly what the trouble is here.  But we can reason about it.  The software is telling you that $user is always empty.  That means that

```
doc('credentials.xml')/credenziali/utente[./user = $login]
```

evaluates to the empty sequence.  If it were my code, I'd now check the following:

- Does $login have a value?
- Is doc('credentials.xml') empty?
- If non-empty, does it have an outermost element named credenziali?
- If so, does credenziali have children (or:  a child) named utente?
- If so, does utente have a child named user?  (Why would an element named `utente` have a child named `user`, I ask myself.  Shouldn't it be `username` or something?  But, hey, it's your XML, not mine, you call things what you like.  I'm just showing you that I'm paying attention.)
- If so, do any of the user elements have a string value which is identical to to the value of $login?

If the answer to all of those questions is yes, then you have a really interesting and challenging issue, and perhaps a bug report for your XQuery engine.

If I had to bet, without knowing anything more than I do, I'd bet on the first two questions -- because they involve interacting with the environment, which is (a) non-standardized, (b) often complicated by considerations that seem extraneous, (c) often very difficult for the library creator to document well (since they can't know everything they need to know about *your* environment), and so (d) often not documented particularly well, and thus (e) error prone.  I find trial and error helps a lot.

[postscript]

You ask how to check to see whether $login and $user are being initialized correctly.  There are no rules or limits here.  Debugging XQuery is a lot like debugging any other programming language; you need to find ways to make what is going on in the code visible on your screen, so you can figure out where things are going wrong.  Some possibilities:

- Temporarily replace the initialization of the variables with something like

  ```
  let $login :=  "Paolo",
      $password :=  "Francesca"
      $usersdoc := <credenziali> 
                     <utente id="1"> 
                       <user>Paolo</user> 
                       <password>Francesca</password> 
                     </utente> 
                   </credenziali>
   let $user := $usersdoc//utente[./user = $login]
  ```

  Make sure this works.  (If it doesn't, your problem is somewhere else.)  Then replace the initialization of $login with the original code and see if it still works.  If it does, replace the initialization of $password and see if it still works.  If it does, replace the initialization of $usersdoc, and then $user.
- Remove the conditional and return, unconditionally, some value that allows you to see the value of $login.  (E.g.

  ```
  let $login :=  request:get-parameter("username",'')
  let $password :=  request:get-parameter("password",'')

  let $user := doc('credentials.xml')
                 /credenziali/utente
                 [./user = $login]

  return concat('staff.xq...',$login,'...',$password)
  ```

  I'm guessing that the string returned by your login function is the URI to which the user is going to be redirected -- if that's so, should you not have a slash or something between 'staff.xq' and the login id?  If it's not the URI to which the user is being redirected, you may need to adjust things in the caller so you can see what values are being emitted for $login and $password.
- Use trace(), if your XQuery engine produces logs you can inspect.

Comment: Yes for all your questions:) 
Because in my code there is: 
<input name="username" type="text" ... etc>
and credentials.xml cotain:
<credenziali>
    <utente id="1">
        <user>admin</user>
        <password>admin</password>
    </utente>
</credenziali>
and i set, in the respective input text box, of screen username=admin and password=admin

Comment: Having a field named 'username' in the form and having data in the $login variable are not quite the same thing; have you checked for the value of $login (i.e. for the successful execution of the request:get-parameter() function?  Have you checked that the call to doc() is being executed successfully?

Comment: ok you're right...but i'm beginner with xquery! can i check the value of $login? can i control if the call of doc(credentials.xml ..) do it wright? thanks

Comment: with this example i found, for now, that first problem is that the operation $login=request:get-parameter(...) failed (in fact you're first code, without it, works)! i'll show you how i take data from input: <td><font color="white">Username: </font><br/></td>
            <td><input name="username" type="text" id="username" maxlength="15"/></td>

Comment: At this point, it might be a good idea to (a) say here which XQuery engine you're using, and which library the get-parameter function is in, (b) re-read the vendor's documentation for the library, (c) pose a question on the vendor's product-specific help forum, and/or (d) pose a new Stack Overflow question focusing specifically on request:get-parameter().